# Is it ok to say you want to come to campus interview another day?

Tags: job-search, interview

I’m shortlisted for a campus interview. I am asked if I can do it in few days. I’m nervous because it is very little time to prepare my research talk and teaching lesson. Can I tell them that the proposed date is too soon and would it be possible to do it at a later day? Would it go against me?

Comment: What position is this for?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly request to move the interview a few days from that proposed interview date. BTW, you can also post this question on Stack Exchange Workplace at : https://workplace.stackexchange.com

Comment: Which country are you from? In the subcontinent, it might go against you.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for a different date. You dont necessarily need to tell them that it is because its not enough time for you to prepare. I actually asked for a different date because the proposed one was not too convenient for me and they said another date will not be possible as they will be very busy later. I think you can always just try and ask, if they say not you can just say that you will adjust your plans then and no harm done.

Answer (score 1):

You can always ask, but there are often many candidates that need to be interviewed and as a consequence, asking for a different date is an inconvenience to the department. It may also not be possible to move the date by any substantial amount: there is typically a deadline by which everyone has to be interviewed, and that deadline is typically at the end of the period during which candidates are scheduled to show up. As a consequence, you might be able to move an interview date by a week, but probably not by a month.

Of course, it might also be useful to point out that you will *never* be perfectly prepared. All anyone can ask you is to do your best -- so get on with getting prepared, and do what you can in the time allowed.